# Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, properties, jenkins-pipeline

I have create job template at Jenkins and created jobs based out of template. But when I added properties: `Set Job properties -> Build Triggers -> Build periodically` code to schedule jenkins job execution, the relation of job with template is removing after first execution and job became stand alone job. Whatever change I made to template is not picking by the job after that. Is there a option to schedule jobs while using job template?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly if you create a new job after modification of template , the changes are reflected but the changes are not reflected in the existing job?

It could be a bug in older version of jenkins. Try to configure the existing jobs and save it again to make the changes reflected.

Comment: We are using latest version of cloudbees. problem is, if I create a job out of template which has properties command added and after first execution job will not have any link to template. it will stand as regular pipeline job.